# user32.dll CallNextHookEx - hhk parameter - deprecated? needed for what os?

Tags: c#

In the Microsoft documentation it states, that the hhk parameter is ignored. It does not state any condition that this parameter is not ignored and needed. This leads me to believe, that i can just put NULL without any drawbacks. Is this correct? Why then is this parameter still there?

[Here is the link to the documentation in question.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It has been around for 25 years.  Really mattered back in Windows 3.1, the version that ran on a 386SUX in 16-bit mode and only needed 640 kilobytes of memory.  The entire OS needed less space than the wallpaper bitmap on your monitor.  They made it better.

Comment: Thanks, my curiousity has been satisfied. :) Is there a reason why they didn't overload the method/function to not use that parameter at all when they changed it to "is ignored" and marked the old function as deprecated to slowly cycle it out?

Comment: What would you prefer?  1: keep doing what you've been doing.  2: we added another way to do the same thing.  But v2 only works in yadayada and you have to use v1 in case of yadayadayada.  Oh, and never try the run the v2 program on an OS that can only run v1, your customer has to upgrade.  Sorry if they need OSv1 to keep their ancient no-longer-supported account system going, not our problem.

Comment: I come from a Java background and flagging methods or classes as deprecated is something that is done frequently. (removing the method takes longer ofc). I guess there is pros and cons to both approaches. Thanks for your answers, when I stumble upon an "this is ignored" again I won't be surprised, thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be ignored if your using the API on an "NT kernel" based platform, whereas it is required on the older 9x based ones (95, 98, Me).

- http://www.klenotic.com/pl/null_hhook/